# C# counting characters

Tags: c#

I am trying to complete a brain teaser which has a bug and I cant find it. Just wondering if anyone knows the answer. My goal is to return the character that appears most often.

```
public string solution(string S)
{
    int[] occurrences = new int[26];
    foreach (char ch in S)
    {
        occurrences[ch - 'a']++;
    }

    char best_char = 'a';
    int best_res = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (occurrences[i] >= best_res)
        {
            best_char = (char)('a' + i);
            best_res = occurrences[i];
        }
    }
    return best_char.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You know that Visual Studio comes with a great debugger, right?

Comment: Could you please further specify what kind of bug you mean?

Comment: 'occurrences[ch - 'a']++;' what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

You have small mistake. Your index should start from 0, not 1

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    if (occurrences[i] >= best_res)
    {
        best_char = (char)('a' + i);
        best_res = occurrences[i];
    }
}
```

Another and safer version is that

```
public string Solution(string text)
{
    string strResponse = string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<char, int>> occurance = text.GroupBy(ch => ch)
                                                      .Where(grp => char.IsLetter(grp.Key))
                                                      .Select(grp => new KeyValuePair<char, int>(grp.Key, grp.Count()))
                                                      .OrderByDescending(c => c.Value)
                                                      .ToList();

        if (occurance.Any())
            strResponse = occurance.First().Key.ToString();
    }
    return strResponse;
}
```

Comment: Please do not repost the full code, but only rather the part that has to be fixed, it's easier to read if you do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string solution(string S)
{
    var charDict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    foreach (char c in S.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)))
    {
        if(!charDict.TryGetValue(c, out int count))
        {
            charDict[c] = 1;
        }
        charDict[c]++;

    }

    return charDict.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value).First().Key.ToString();
}
```

Using a dictionary and LINQ is going to be better I think. Don't just copy this code and paste it into what ever homework or class this is for, use it to learn otherwise its a waste of my time and yours really

Answer (score 0):

There could actually be more than one character with the maximum number of occurrences, so:

```
private static Char[] GetMostFrequentChars(String text)
{
    Dictionary<Char,Int32> rank = new Dictionary<Char,Int32>();

    foreach (Char c in text.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)))
    {
        if (rank.ContainsKey(c))
            rank[c]++;
        else
            rank.Add(c, 1);
    }

    return rank.Where(r => r.Value == rank.Values.Max()).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about special characters (like spaces), you could do this with LINQ:

```
public static GetMostFrequentCharacter(string value)
{
    return value
        .GroupBy(o => o)
        .OrderByDescending(o => o.Count())
        .First()
        .Key
        .ToString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 problems:

- as @Adem Çatamak says, for loop should start at index 0
- ch - 'a' will throw an exception if the string contains any other character than a-z lowercase,